# Why were monopoles raining?

Tags: robotics-notes

I just watched Robotics;Notes. The manga not yet.

A monopole fell from the sky. And later, lots more begun raining.

It was a recurring theme in the series that there was a solar flare cooking up, so I was under the impression that it was also making funny things in the earth's atmosphere kinda explaining the monopoles.

But later in the series we find out that

> There is no solar flare at all. All the info about it is fake.

So, what's up with the monopoles?

My next guess was that it was part of

> Kimijima Kou's plan to make the whole solar flare thing more realistic by somehow synthesising monopoles and throwing them off the sky (somehow)

But I'm not sure if that's confirmed in the series or the manga.

Comment: You could chalk it to a deus ex machina... there seem to be a lot of unanswered question like: how exactly an AI take over someone mind? How can you make people see an AR object IRL? Why an anime director be privy to a doomsday plot and not be succumb to an "accidental" death? There has to be more to the Committee of 300, why would they just laze around and do nothing while their plans fall apart? Also why does a doomsday device test that give the main protagonist his special power? Besides Akiho, why does no one else have a similar powers?

Comment: @Krazer: Regarding the powers thing, isn't it because only Kai and Aki survived the experiment thanks to Misaki's intervention? (Dunno what she did exactly though)

Comment: monopole is real, you can see it in wikipedia which has a lot of explanation. xD
robotics;notes was my favourite show :D

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Reading Steiner in [this question on ask.fm](http://ask.fm/SciADV/answer/121050122039), this isn't actually covered in the anime, but in the VN, Kai knocked the HAARP Radar into the sweet spot for electromagnetic interference, creating them.

Reading Steiner clarifies a lot of things on his ask.fm over at http://ask.fm/SciADV.

Comment: Can you provide an approximate point of reference in the visual novel?